# 'ValueError: could not convert string to float' or 'ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [163423, 1]'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Came into error when executing the code below:

```
for dirs, listdir, files in os.walk(Result_DIR):
    for file in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(Result_DIR, file)
        FMout = open(file_path)
        predict = []
        for line in FMout.readlines():
            line = line.strip('\n')
            print type(line)
            predict.append(line)
        auc = roc_auc_score(lables, predict)
        print ('FM AUC= %f' % auc, file)
```

And the error is:

```
<type 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/fmAUC_all.py", line 29, in <module> 
  auc = roc_auc_score(lables, predict)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/ranking.py", line 260, in roc_auc_score
  sample_weight=sample_weight)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/base.py", line 84, in _average_binary_score
  return binary_metric(y_true, y_score, sample_weight=sample_weight)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/ranking.py", line 255, in _binary_roc_auc_score
  sample_weight=sample_weight)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/ranking.py", line 505, in roc_curve
  y_true, y_score, pos_label=pos_label, sample_weight=sample_weight)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/ranking.py", line 297, in _binary_clf_curve
  check_consistent_length(y_true, y_score)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 181, in check_consistent_length
  " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [163423, 1]
```

When I change the line to:

```
print type(line)
predict.append(float(line))
```

I get this error:

```
<type 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/fmAUC_all.py", line 26, in <module>
predict.append(float(line))ValueError: could not convert string to float
```

Totally confused because when I execute some of the datasets which are the same form as the ones I use in the above, everything just works well.

Comment: You get `ValueError: could not convert string to float:` because at least one of your lines isn't a number. For the first error, it isn't caused by the code that you show us - there's no mention of anything related to `sklearn` in it. Some of your datasets probably contain invalid data...

Comment: Post full stack trace of both errors with the code causing them